# Python 3 exceptions with long messages are kind of unreadable

Tags: python-3.x, exception

I know there are lot of questions that are kind of similar to this, but none of them seem to really address what I want to know. Suppose I throw an exception in my python package somewhere, and give a long message to help the user avoid the problem:

```
if list(par_names)[0] is not "scan":
    raise SanityCheckException("Error in signature of user-supplied log-likelihood function! The first argument must be named 'scan' and will be passed a reference to a global ScannerBit object that can be used to e.g. print extra information to the scan output file.")
```

My problem is that the message comes out rather unreadable when the error is triggered:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "basic_test.py", line 37, in <module>
    myscan = sb.Scan(test_logl, bounds=[[1., 40.]] * 3, prior_types=["flat", "flat", "log"], prior_func=prior, scanner="twalk", settings=settings, model_name='model1')
  File "/home/farmer/anaconda3/envs/general/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyscannerbit/scan.py", line 116, in __init__
    raise SanityCheckException("Error in signature of user-supplied log-likelihood function! The first argument must be named 'scan' and will be passed a reference to a global ScannerBit object that can be used to e.g. print extra information to the scan output file.")
pyscannerbit.scan.SanityCheckException: Error in signature of user-supplied log-likelihood function! The first argument must be named 'scan' and will be passed a reference to a global ScannerBit object that can be used to e.g. print extra information to the scan output file.
```

I mean you can dig it out of there if you try, but it is not nice to read. I could catch the error, print the message more nicely, then re-throw it (to get the traceback) but then I am just going to end up with the long message printed three times rather than two.

What is the actual best practice here? I have no idea what I am "supposed" to do when I want to write a long message to the user.

Comment: I'm not sure what answer you are looking for here. You pass a long string to `SanityCheckException` then ""complain"" that you get a long string in the traceback. You can try to use a multiline string or add some `\n` throughout the string

Comment: Well I don't just mean that. My terminal wraps it just fine, though sure I can manually add some newlines to make it a bit nicer. But I still get at least the first line duplicated, and the error doesn't really stand out of the traceback. I guess I'd prefer if the traceback didn't include the error at all (I guess I should put it in a variable?). Maybe stick a newline at the beginning and end so it doesn't "blend in" to the traceback so much? I am just wondering what others do with long error messages, or if there are some conventions I should follow perhaps.